# Gtk notifications don't display body holding '<'

Tags: python, notifications, gtk, pygobject

I'm trying to display notifications with the Notification module of pygobject (version 3.16) in python. My code works well, except when there is a `<` in the body message. In this case, the body is not displayed.

For example with this code, all is OK:

```
from gi.repository import Gtk, Notify

def callback(notification, action_name):
    notification.close()
    Gtk.main_quit()

Notify.init('test')
notification = Notify.Notification.new('Title', 'body')
notification.set_timeout(Notify.EXPIRES_NEVER)
notification.add_action('quit', 'Quit', callback)
notification.show()

Gtk.main()
```

But with this one there is a problem:

```
from gi.repository import Gtk, Notify

def callback(notification, action_name):
    notification.close()
    Gtk.main_quit()

Notify.init('test')
notification = Notify.Notification.new('Title', '<body')
notification.set_timeout(Notify.EXPIRES_NEVER)
notification.add_action('quit', 'Quit', callback)
notification.show()

Gtk.main()
```

I get that: [image: Notification where the body is not displayed]

When the `<` is in the title, or when I use a `>` there is no problem.

I tried to escape the `<`, but it didn't do anything.
So, how could I display a body text containing a `<` ?

Comment: The '<' displays fine for me. Could it be a font issue?

Comment: I don't think: there is no problem when the '<' is in the title, and the '>' is fine in the body.

Comment: What desktop environment and version are you running?

Comment: How did you escape the `<`? This is not specified in the libnotify documentation, but some (all?) notification servers use GMarkup (a subset of HTML) so you have to escape it using `&lt;`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've noticed that in Gtk there is sometimes html code, like when using `set_markup`.I tried with the hmtl equivalent `&lt;` and it worked fine:

```
from gi.repository import Gtk, Notify

def callback(notification, action_name):
    notification.close()
    Gtk.main_quit()

Notify.init('test')
notification = Notify.Notification.new('Title', '&lt;body&gt;')
notification.set_timeout(Notify.EXPIRES_NEVER)
notification.add_action('quit', 'Quit', callback)
notification.show()
```